# Capture output from SOX "-n stat"

Tags: pipe, stdout, sox

I am trying to capture/pipe the output from the following:

arecord -f S16_LE -qd 5 file && sox file -n stat

output:

Samples read:              8000
Length (seconds):      1.000000
Scaled by:         2147483647.0
Maximum amplitude:     0.992188
Minimum amplitude:    -0.992188
Midline amplitude:     0.000000
Mean    norm:          0.093221
Mean    amplitude:    -0.015338
RMS     amplitude:     0.232947
Maximum delta:         0.617188
Minimum delta:         0.000000
Mean    delta:         0.001067
RMS     delta:         0.009643
Rough   frequency:           52
Volume adjustment:        1.008

I need to capture the data to convert to json. Issue is "SOX" seems to defy any method I would normally use to capture/pipe the stdout. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sox is sending this output to stderr.

In order to redirect stderr, try running something along the lines of

```
arecord -f S16_LE -qd 5 file && sox file -n stat    2> output.txt
```

Or send it to a pipe (ex `wc`)

```
arecord -f S16_LE -qd 5 file && sox file -n stat  2>&1 | wc
```